# How to get detailed query execution statistics for each algebra operator or primitive on Postgresql or MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql, rdbms, relational-algebra

I need to obtain statical information (execution time, main memory footprint and so on) for every single algebra operator or primitive from a query on MySQL or PostgreSQL.

I get those statistics using the Trace statement of MonetDB -> https://www.monetdb.org/Documentation/Manuals/SQLreference/Trace

But, I've researched a lot on MySQL and PostgreSQL and I couldn't find any straightforward method like in MonetDB. In which when a query is executed with the Trace statement some pre-defined statistics are registered into the sys.tracelog table for every single primitive of that query. I wish something similar on both DBMSes. I have seen the explain statement, but I need a detailed output for each primitive of a query like on MonetDB.

In order to be more clear when I said algebra or primitive could be interpreted as any function (primitive) or algorithm that is used by the DBMS to execute the query. The DBMS transforms the query plan to a physical plan that contains a tree of functions (codes) to be execute in the CPU, so I need the execution time and the memory usage (footprint) for every relevant function of the physical plan. MonetDB already provides that with the Trace statement.

Comment: You can be told how to get at SQL execution statistics avaliable under a given DBMS, but re your stated goal & titile, it's not clear what you could even mean by "get detailed query execution statistics for each algebra operator or primitive on Postgresql or MySQL" since SQL queries are not implemented in terms of "agebra operators", are not implemented 1:1 with their syntax tree and do not denote calls to just one operator or primitive. So it is also not clear what you could mean by such statistics.

Comment: @philipxy thanks for your reply. In order to be more  clear when I said algebra or primitive could be interpreted as any function (primitive) or algirithm that is used by the DBMS to execute the query. The DBMS casts the query plan to a phisical plan that contains a tree of functions (codes) to be execute in the CPU, so I need the execution time and the memory usage  (footprint) for every relevant function of the phisical plan. MonetDB already provides that with the Trace statement.

Comment: Please edit clarifications into your posts, not comments.